# Use array in a Django template file

Tags: django-templates

I know that in a template you can use for statement in an HTML file.
e.g.:

```
{% for item in array %}
<!-- do something -->
{% endfor %}
```

Is there a way to access an array in a template without using a `for` loop? Like `{{values[0}}`?

I am using Python and Django.

Comment: There is no loop in pure HTML. Are you using any programming language? Which one? You forgot to specify that in your question.

Comment: python and django

Comment: If your question is about [the django template language](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/templates/language/) then talk about that, not HTML. HTML is not a programming language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the variables from the list using indexing.

```
{{ array.0 }}
```